# Extract data from the last N lines of a txt file into arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, file-handling

I am trying to extract data of different types, enclosed in multiple types of whitespaces, from the last N lines of a txt file into arrays in python

I have tried using the split() function to split the data, but not able to get the correct split items since there are multiple different types of whitspace characters between the data I want to actually separate and store

This is a sample of the text file that I have :

```
{"2019-03-29": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-03-29": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-03-29": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-03-29": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-03-29": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-04-01": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-04-01": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-04-01": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-04-01": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]}, 

{"2019-04-01": [["A", "B", "C"], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]},
```

I would like to be able to extract data out of the *last* 6 lines for eg, and get the following results :

(arr1 of dimensions 6x1)

```
arr1 = [ [2019-03-29] , [2019-04-01] , [2019-04-01], [2019-04-01] , [2019-04-01] , [2019-04-01] ]
```

(arr2 of dimensions 6x7)

```
arr2 = [[0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Is this a `json` file?

Comment: @Rakesh It sort of looks like one, but its just a log file, that is logging this data in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the lines and keep the last six in an array.

```
with open('jsons.txt') as jsons:
    lines = []
    for line in jsons:
        lines.append(line)
        if len(lines) > 6:
            lines.pop(0)
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
for line in lines:
    j = json.loads(line)
    for k in j:
        arr1.append([k])
        arr2.append(j[k][0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line as a Json object that will map to a List of Dictionary with a List of objects.

You have some examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

But basically, read each line and call **json.loads(line)** and you'll get a Dictionary for each line.

From there you can get operate as usual with Python and get whatever you need.

Answer (score -1):

Read the file in reverse to get last 6 lines.

```
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
    print(line.strip())
```

spilt the lines using spilt() function on ':' symbol:-

```
line.spilt(':')
```

Add date and list of list([[]]) to different lists. later format the second list obtained into a list of the desired format using nested for loop.